# Android - Programmatically Extract Contents of .apk

Tags: android

What my app will be doing is copying a .apk from the /data/app folder, extract the contents of it, and then copy files into it, repackage it, sign it, and copy it back. My current issue is extracting the .apk file, most people say its just like a .zip file but I am having issues with it. I have been able to extract .zip files no problem, but even after renaming the .apk to .zip it doesnt go. I was able to extract it with ES File Explorer, repackage it as a .zip and my app would work and extract the .zip and continue to repackage it and once installed again everything worked fine. Is there some sort of library made to handle this kind of file? I have tried standard Java to extract, Zip4J, and Apache Commons, which have lead to no avail. Any help is appreciated, thanks!